# React Navigation upgrading 4.x to 5.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: Main,
        },
        AddList: {
            screen: AddList,
        },
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
    },
);
```

I changed my code  due to the new version for react navigation but I dont know how to implement the last part from the above code. Im not sure if i use Stack.Screen to implement headerMode and navigationoptions or Stack.navigator

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function RootStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Screen
      headerMode: 'none'
      options={{header: null}}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddList"
        component={AddList}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
      />
    </Stack.Screen>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

headerMode and navigationoptions are not working anymore.
Now you have to use the props `screenOptions` of the Stack.Navigator (which is surrounding Stack.Screen)

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function RootStack() {
  return (
 <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{  headerShown: false }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen
      name="AddList"
      component={AddList}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={Profile}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: is headerVisisble same as headerShown?

Comment: yes, you can check the documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#specifying-navigationoptions-for-a-screen

Comment: I have bunch of CreateNavigationContainer() and i want to wrap my MainStack using NavigationContainer so basically doing export default CreateAppContainer (MainStack) in version 4.x

Comment: would i just do <NavigationContainer> inside MainStack then? because for App.js im doing <Navigation/>

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking, but I have 2 projects with react navigation 5, what I just do is adding <NavigationContainer> in the render of the top component. Then just below <NavigationContainer> I have { RootStack() }

Comment: So you also have a Tab Navigator ? you should check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: hey, if you dont mind can you help a little bite more https://codeshare.io/GAR08e im having trouble with doing render part

Comment: I checked your code, so 1)  you can't have 2 createStackNavigator 2) what is the difference between home and main component ?